rqt topic monitor can display topics but ros2 topic list times out
I'm having some issues with ros2 (rolling) dds communication. In my case, ros2 topic list times out with this error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ccccc/ros2/rolling/install/ros2cli/bin/ros2", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('ros2cli', 'console_scripts', 'ros2')())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ccccc/ros2/rolling/build/ros2cli/ros2cli/cli.py", line 91, in main
    rc = extension.main(parser=parser, args=args)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ccccc/ros2/rolling/build/ros2topic/ros2topic/command/topic.py", line 41, in main
    return extension.main(args=args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ccccc/ros2/rolling/build/ros2topic/ros2topic/verb/list.py", line 55, in main
    with NodeStrategy(args) as node:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ccccc/ros2/rolling/build/ros2cli/ros2cli/node/strategy.py", line 27, in __init__
    if use_daemon and is_daemon_running(args):
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ccccc/ros2/rolling/build/ros2cli/ros2cli/node/daemon.py", line 75, in is_daemon_running
    return node.connected
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ccccc/ros2/rolling/build/ros2cli/ros2cli/node/daemon.py", line 46, in connected
    for method in self._proxy.system.listMethods()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1122, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1461, in __request
    response = self.__transport.request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1166, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1178, in single_request
    http_conn = self.send_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1291, in send_request
    self.send_content(connection, request_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1321, in send_content
    connection.endheaders(request_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1331, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1091, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1035, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1001, in connect
    self.sock = self._create_connection(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/socket.py", line 852, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/socket.py", line 837, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

but if I use rqt "Topic Monitor", the topics (andt their content) can be displayed.
How should I debug into it? I'm compiling ros2 from source, so I can change the source code and then debug.

if I use ros2 topic list --no-daemon, it works.
